# C drive shows as full, despite not being full

Tags: windows, storage, windows-10

Specs:

- Win10 Pro
- 1x 256gb HDD
- 1x 1tb HDD

I have an issue on this particular machine where the C drive becomes full and says there are 0 bytes free. Deleting programs or files does nothing to change this and disk clean-up can remove a maximum of 31mb. I have reinstalled Windows 10 on this machine 3 times now, the day that I do the reinstall, everything is working fine with 200gb of free disk space after the windows install, give it a couple of nights and suddenly it is full again.

The below image shows that even Windows can't figure out why the drive is full. Once the drive is full, any attempts I have made to clear it are useless, and eventually, core Windows features like the settings and start menu no longer function.

[Win10 storage settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvuB0.png)

Any help with this will be much appreciated, I'm probably going to buy a new drive in the meantime, but it's such a strange issue and I feel like it is software related as the drive works perfectly fine for a few days, then suddenly has this issue.

Edit:
After checking the specs in cmd, the drive seems to think it is a hard drive, I have updated this above. The drive is deceivingly fast though, Windows boots in just a few seconds.

[image: Below is the output of the command]

Comment: This question appears to be off topic. We do not accept questions about home computers and networks. You may be able to get help on our sister site [su].

Comment: Runing dir /a /s >d:\list.txt  in c:\ will create a file on D drive with a list of all files. Additionally run chkdsk - this might be a HDD problem

Answer (score 1):

Check this out. windirstat https://windirstat.net/  Hope this helps.

"To figure out where your space has gone use windirstat https://windirstat.net/
Run this utility as a administrator (right click on the icon and run as administrator)"

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2268791-c-drive-showing-minimum-space-available-but-the-actual-space-is-more